# Adding an NSTextField as a subview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nstextfield

I'm trying to add an `NSTextField` as a subview of a custom view class I have (which subclasses `NSView`), and then make the `NSTextField` the first responder. This works fine. The text field shows up and I can start typing in it.  However, any mouse events in the text field seem to fall through to its `superview`. For example, I can't see the mouse cursor when I hover over the text field, and when I click anywhere in the text field, it attempts to resign firstResponder status instead of letting me select text within the text field.

I'm not overriding `hitTest` or anything weird like that, and I only have one window, which is definitely the key window.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: what kind of stuff do you do in your custom View?

Comment: It's mostly just logic to draw the view and handle things like dragging and dropping.